# What kind of members should be used in a GetHashCode() implementation

Tags: c#, hashing

We're building some Roslyn analyzers concerning `GetHashCode()`, including an analyzer that implements it for you in a given class.

While researching the subject we've found that there are many considerations to take into account, mainly on what kind of members should be avoided in a `GetHashCode()` implementation.

The main kind of member to avoid are mutable members (to avoid hashcode changes when used in a collection).

> In general, for mutable reference types, you should override `GetHashCode` only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable

[[Source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now the question that remains: what kind of members are we talking about then? The member has to be immutable but then again it should also be (ideally) different for each instance otherwise you'll just end up with the same hashcode for every object.

This leads me to conclude that the only acceptable members for a `GetHashCode()` implementation are *readonly immutable structs* and *readonly immutable classes* Note: not `const`. Likewise no `static` fields since they would be the same across instances anyway.

The way this would be implemented in reality would be by using a

- Field: `readonly T myField`
- Property: `T myProp { get; }`

Since it would be very not feasible to detect if a class is immutable, we should probably eliminate that entirely aside from `string` perhaps.

This leaves the list of applicable members for a `GetHashCode()` implementation to:

- Readonly fields
- And getter-only properties
- That are immutable structs
- And aren't `static`
- And aren't interfaces
- + `string`

Does that seem correct or have I made a mistake in the thought process somewhere? It seems like we're suddenly left with a lot less fields than people typically use. I realize that there is a pragmatic aspect to this that just says "add all the fields and let the dev figure it out" but I try to avoid introducing hidden bugs in the analyzers.

Comment: Less is more. Stick to members you **know** you can safely include in an automagic `GetHashCode` implementation, and let the dev manually add whatever else they might need - if anything. Or do you intend VSD to always generate a foul-proof `GetHashCode` implementation for *anything*?

Comment: “Since it would be very not feasible to detect if a class is immutable”: what about classes which override `GetHashCode()`? They would be in turn checked by the analyzers and so would be assumed to be immutable as well.

Comment: @MainMa I can check if a class overrides `GetHashCode()` but I can't check what subclasses do. For example `class B : A` where `B` is mutable can be placed in a field of type `A`. I can look at `A`'s implementation (assuming I even have those sources available -- ergo, they're user-defined) but the field might as well get filled with an object of type `B` with the bad implementation. Structs don't have this issue because they can't be subclassed -- I know exactly which type will go in the field.

Comment: 1. What about primitive types, like int, double and enum?  Obviously those are similar to strings, but your rules appear to exclude them.  2. If you provide a `.GetHashCode()`, are you also going to provide an `.Equals()` ?

Comment: @ErikEidt those are `structs` and are definitely included (bullet 3). Regarding Equals: yes, that is taken care of already and there we just use every field -- the rules are much more relaxed since we don't have to take a hash miss into account.

Comment: Would your rules include this? public  int Random { get { return new Random().Next(0,100); } }

Comment: @MattiasÅslund they would because that's impossible to rule out (unless you ignore all properties altogether). In this case I thought it okay considering I haven't seen a pattern like this very much aside from lazy loading (which will still only do it once).

Comment: And I guess your rules would rule out primary keys for db entities, which I think is unfortunate. They are usually never changed (except during insert) but seldom marked readonly.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund I'd go as far as saying that your property implementation is a bug: getters must be referentially transparent as long as the owning object hasn't been mutated. Otherwise things break. Try inspecting the property value in the debug inspector, for instance.

Comment: I recommend reading Eric Lippert's excellent article, [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/).  Fundamentally, the answer to your question is that you must ensure that all equal items have equal hashes. The converse is not required.

Answer (score 3):

> Readonly fields

This goes without saying.

> And getter-only properties

Yes, as long as by "getter-only properties" we strictly mean `type prop { get; }`

> That are immutable structs

Yes, in the sense that in C# primitives are also implemented as immutable structs.

> And aren't static

This goes without saying.

> And aren't interfaces

This goes without saying too, but do keep in mind that you can always involve the identity hashcode of an interface if you need to.

> - string

Again, goes without saying.

The fact that you are wondering so hard about how to implement `GetHashCode()` may be indicative of confusion about when to implement `GetHashCode()` and when not to.  There are two types of objects:

- Objects with value semantics
- Objects with reference ("object") semantics.

Objects with value semantics are used for storing values.  They should always be immutable and should always implement `GetHashCode()` taking into consideration every single one of their members.

Objects with reference semantics contain logic, and usually some state.  They will usually *not* be immutable, (though it is possible in rare circumstances,) but one thing that is certain about them is that they will never be used as values, therefore they never need to override the default `GetHashCode()` implementation of `object`, which returns the identity hashcode of the object.

Comment: What if I adjust the involvement of properties to only properties that have no setter and a getter without implementation? In essence this would reduce it to a `readonly` field:can be assigned inline and in the constructor but nowhere else. It would only get one value: `public int MyProp { get; } = new Random().Next();` returns always the same. As a sidenote: I don't know why you separate 'primitives' from 'immutable structs' -- primitives are a Java term and are implemented as immutable structs in C# as far as I know.

Comment: Okay, correct on both counts.  I misunderstood what you meant by getter-only properties, and I momentarily forgot C#'s nifty trick of implementing primitives as immutable structs.  I will amend my answer.